# Conditional styling in react map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I only want to show the display block on the hovered item. but when I hover it shows on every item in a map function. what I'm doing wrong.

[image] basically, I just want to show hovered movie item's title. for now, it shows every movie when I hover.

MovieList.js

```
  const [popular, setPopular] = useState([]);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="movie-list">
        <h2 style={{ fontSize: "49px", marginLeft: "60px" }}>What's Popular</h2>

        <div className="popular">
          {popular.map((pop, index) => (
            <>
              <div className="movie" key={index}>
                <div className="tot" onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}>
                  <h4
                    id="pop-title"
                    style={{ display: hover ? "block" : "none" }}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    {pop.title}
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <img
                  src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + pop.poster_path}
                  id="movie-img"
                />
              </div>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The same `hover` state variable is used for all your movies, so when it becomes true, all the movies are affected by the change. You could use something like an object instead of just a boolean to store one hover state per movie.

Another problem with your code that isn't helping:

You are missing a unique `key` prop on each item of the `map` (it must be on the direct child).

Solution 1: Remove the Fragment

Everything is already under one `div` so you don't need the React Fragment (`<>`) in that case. Also, you might wanna use something unique to the current map item other than the index in the array.

```
{popular.map((pop) => (
    <div className="movie" key={pop.somethingUnique}>
        <div className="tot" onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}>
            <h4 id="pop-title" style={{ display: hover ? "block" : "none" }}>
                {pop.title}
            </h4>
        </div>
        <img
            src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + pop.poster_path}
            id="movie-img"
        />
    </div>
))}
```

Solution 2: Set the key on the Fragment

```
{popular.map((pop) => (
    <Fragment key={pop.somethingUnique}>
        <div className="movie">
            <div className="tot" onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}>
                <h4 id="pop-title" style={{ display: hover ? "block" : "none" }}>
                    {pop.title}
                </h4>
            </div>
            <img
                src={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + pop.poster_path}
                id="movie-img"
            />
        </div>
    </Fragment>
))}
```

Comment: thanks but didn't help when i hover on any movie still shows movie title on all movies. :(